# Replace substring with a regex combination

Tags: java, string

Since I'm not that familiar with java, I don't know if there's a library somewhere that can do this thing. If not, does anybody have any ideas how can this be accomplished?

For instance I have a string "foo" and I want to change the letter f with "f" and "a" so that the function returns a list of strings with values "foo" and "aoo".

How to deal with it when there's more of the same letters? "ffoo" into "ffoo", "afoo", "faoo", "aaoo".

A better explanation:
(("a",("a","b)),("c",("c","d")))
Above is a group of characters that need to be replaced with a character from the other element. "a" is to be replaced with "a" and with "b". "c" is to be replaced with "c" and "d".

If I have a string "ac", the resulting combinations I need are:
"ac"
"bc"
"ad"
"bd"

If the string is "IaJaKc", the resulting combinations are:
"IaJaKc"
"IbJaKc"
"IaJbKc"
"IbJbKc"
"IaJaKd"
"IbJaKd"
"IaJbKd"
"IbJbKd"

The number of combinations can be calculated like this:
(replacements_of_a^letter_amount_a)*(replacements_of_c^letter_amount_c)
first case: 2^1*2^1 = 4
second case: 2^2*2^1 = 8

If, say, the group is (("a",("a","b)),("c",("c","d","e"))), and the string is "aac", the number of combinations is:
2^2*3^1 = 12

Comment: What is the result that you want ?

Comment: To get all the combinations while replacing. I was thinking maybe there's a function that takes a string, letter and regex ("f|a"). Anyways, I need to generate string variants based on replacing a certain letter with several others. It's a character by character substitution. The number of combinations can be calculated, but I don't know how to generate them all..

Comment: I've updated my answer, look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
public static void returnVariants(String input){
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuffer word = new StringBuffer(input);
        output.add(input);

        String letters = "ac";
        int lettersLength = letters.length();
        int wordLength = word.length();
        String replacement = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < lettersLength; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < wordLength; j++) {
                if(word.charAt(j)==letters.charAt(i)){
                    if (word.charAt(j)=='a'){
                        replacement = "ab";
                    }else if (word.charAt(j)=='c'){
                        replacement = "cd";
                    }
                    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int k = 0; k < replacement.length(); k++) {
                        for (String variant : output){
                            StringBuffer tempBuffer = new StringBuffer(variant);
                            String combination = tempBuffer.replace(j, j+1, replacement.substring(k, k+1)).toString();
                            tempList.add(combination);
                        }
                    }
                    output.addAll(tempList);
                    if (j==0){
                        output.remove(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Set<String> uniqueCombinations = new HashSet(output);
        System.out.println(uniqueCombinations);
    }
```

If input is "ac", the combinations returned are "ac", "bc", "ad", "bd". If it can be optimized further, any additional help is welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for your example with foo and aoo

```
public List<String> doSmthTricky (String str) {
    return Arrays.asList("foo".replaceAll("(^.)(.*)", "$1$2 a$2").split(" "));
}
```

For the input "foo" this method returns a list with 2 strings "foo" and "aoo".

It works only if there is no whitespaces in your input string ("foo" in your example). Otherwise it's a bit more complicated.

> How to deal with it when there's more of the same letters? "ffoo" into "ffoo", "afoo", "faoo", "aaoo".

I doubt that regular expressions could help here, you want to generate strings based on initial string, it's not a task for regexp.

**UPD**: I've created a recursive function (actually it's half-recursive half-iterative) which generates strings based on the template string by replacing its first characters with characters from a specified set:

```
public static List<String> generatePermutations (String template, String chars, int depth, List<String> result) {
    if (depth <= 0) {
        result.add (template);
        return result;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++) {
        String newTemplate = template.substring(0, depth - 1) + chars.charAt(i) + template.substring(depth);
        generatePermutations(newTemplate, chars, depth - 1, result);
    }
    generatePermutations(template, chars, depth - 1, result);
    return result;
}
```

Parameter `@depth` means how many characters from the beginning of string should be replaced. Number of permutations `(chars.size() + 1) ^ depth`.

Tests:

```
System.out.println(generatePermutations("ffoo", "a", 2, new LinkedList<String>()));

Output: [aaoo, faoo, afoo, ffoo]

--
System.out.println(generatePermutations("ffoo", "ab", 3, new LinkedList<String>()));

Output: [aaao, baao, faao, abao, bbao, fbao, afao, bfao, ffao, aabo, babo, fabo, abbo, bbbo, fbbo, afbo, bfbo, ffbo, aaoo, baoo, faoo, aboo, bboo, fboo, afoo, bfoo, ffoo]
```

Comment: Roman, thanks for trying, but I still need the other example to work. If I use replaceAll, I can get "ffoo" by doing nothing, and then afterwards "afoo" and "aaoo", but the "faoo" is still missing... :(

Comment: Permutes nicely, but not the solution I need. Sorry if I'm wasting your time :S

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need. Please specify source and the result you expect. Anyway, you should use standard java classes for that purpose: java.util.regex.Pattern, java.util.regex.Matcher. If you need to deal with the repeating letters in the beginning, then there is two ways, use symbol "^" - which means beginning of the line, or for the same purpose you can use "\w" shortcut, which means beginning of the word. In more sophisticated cases, please take a look at "lookbehind" expressions. There are more than complete descriptions of these techniques you can find in java doc for java.util.regex and if it's not enough look at www.regular-expressions.info good luck.

Comment: Not much of the source to show :( Here's a better explanation. I've got a set of characters that I need to replace. Each character in that set needs to be replaced with a character from its distinctive group. The function needs to return all the combinations of the initial string. The characters aren't necessarily at the beginning of the string. The string can be anything, but the group is something like this (("a",("a","b)),("c",("c","d"))). Meaning replace every "a" with "a" and "b", but get all the combinations, likewise with "c", replace it with "c" and "d".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I suppose, in that way, your task is much simpler than it appears before. Moreover, I think you can handle it without regexp at all. On your place, I would put characters-need-to-be-replaced in a collection, then there would be 2 loops: outer on that collection and inner that tests source string on existence of the current character-to-be-replaced, it can be done by indexOf(int pos, String character) method of String. In the inner loop I would fill the returning collection of replaced strings and increase "pos", if the character was found. Hope this will help.

Comment: I was trying to solve it like that, but can't traverse back to cover all of the combinations... it covers all of it from start to end, but gets stuck on the last change of the last letter. If "a" changes to "a" and "b" and "c" to "c" and "d", string "ac" outputs "ac", "bc", "bc" again and "bd"...

Comment: I think I have a solution. I went out for a bit and had time to think about it without being in a mind-lock. I'll post it tomorrow :)